# Is there a difference between std::string's front() and [0]?

Tags: c++, string

In my program I need to check the first character of a `std::string`, and use something like this:

```cpp
if(string.front() == '-')
```

I wonder, does using the code below instead make any difference?

```cpp
if(string[0] == '-')
```

Comment: per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front) `front` returns reference to the first character, equivalent to operator[](0).

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [reference](https://eel.is/c++draft/string.access#8) for `string::front`:

> *Effects:* Equivalent to: `return operator[](0);`

So there is no difference between the 2 snippets of code you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

Both `front()` and `operator[]` returns reference to element, so no difference;

If you needs bounds checking you can use `std::string::at`, which does the boundary checking and throws `std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the difference between `front()` and `operator[](0)` is that both are UB if the string is empty....?

Comment: For op's question, actually no difference, since both `front` and `operator[]` returns reference to element, I wanted to tell op, that if he needs bounds checking, he must use `std::string::at`, maybe I was not clear in my answer, next time, I will try to be more clear on my answers. thanks `@DevSolar`

Comment: But the question was not **about** bounds checking, and no indication that OP needs it...?!?

Comment: @DevSolar edited my answer, to answer op's question and my suggestion at end.